# Why does vscode-eslint use a different "root" than ESLint?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

Everytime I open my project folder in Visual Studio Code, I get an error on the first line of each file. It cannot find my `tsconfig.json` file because it is looking in the directory I opened VS Code, not where my `eslint.json` is. I have a `functions` folder in my root project where the ESLint config is.

Here is part of it:

```
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2019,
    "project": ["./tsconfig.json", "./tsconfig.dev.json"],
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
```

When I run my lint command `eslint "src/*.{ts,js}"`, it works perfectly and shows the correct warnings. This means that the VS Code plugin `dbaeumer.vscode-eslint` parses the `.eslintrc.json` config differently than what it should.

If I change the `project` to `["./functions/tsconfig.json", "./functions/tsconfig.dev.json"]`, then VS Code stops giving the error, but when I run ESLint, it tries to find it in `<path/to/project>/functions/functions/tsconfig.json` going in the functions directory twice.

Is this a VS Code bug, a `dbaeumer.vscode-eslint` bug, or am I doing something wrong? What can I do to fix the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just add this `"eslint.workingDirectories": [{ "mode": "auto" }]` to your VS Code `settings.json`.

It should make the error go away, but it can have unintended side effects.
More Info: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint#settings-options